# How to disable auto word-wrap of tooltip (title), in QWebEngineView

Tags: html, css, qt, qtwebengine

While using `QWebEngineView::setHtml` to display a local Html file, I've noticed that the text of tooltip is auto wrapped. I tried to modify CSS so as to disable the word-wrap, but it doesn't work. On Chrome I don't have this problem.

**[EDIT]**
Try running [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXKWZXK0DNU7) simple HTML example in **Chrome**, and then with **QWebEngineView**, and you'll see the difference. When you hover the `<p>` element in **QWebEngineView** you'll see that the tooltip is *wrapped*, unlike in **Chrome**.

Here's some screenshots :

**QWebEngineView** :

[image: screenshot]

**Chrome** :

[image: screenshot]

This is the Html:

```
<div id="fullSc" class="fullScCls" title="FullScreen (Alt + F11)" onclick="fullSc(this);"><span></span></div>
```

And here's the CSS :

```
.fullScCls {
 width:32px;
 height:32px;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:18pt;
 font-family: IconFont;
 cursor:pointer;

 white-space:pre; // I tried this because it works with QTooltip (rich text)
                  // even if it will affect the div content only, and not its tooltip I think
 }
.fullScCls:hover{
 color:#42AECC;
 transition: .5s;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please break text in the html look like.

```
title="FullScreen 
( Alt + F11)"

Codepen: https://codepen.io/tushar-kumawat/pen/KrROjJ
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer

Comment: I'm not trying to add a line break in the tooltip. I want to disable the auto word-wrap in QWebEngineView, if possible. I don't see a solution in the link.

Comment: Please try again look like: title="FullScreen &#013; ( Alt + F11)"

Comment: I think you misunderstood the issue. Please check the link that I've just added (EDIT section). You ask me to try adding `&#013;`, which is a carriage return, while my problem is to remove those break lines.